# How to include DDK headers in visual studio 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-8

I need to use `ZwLoadDriver` function from *ntddk.h*. I installed [Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hh852363). Set all includes (`#include <ntddk.h>`). And I have lots of errors like `type/sruct redefinition`, `... already has a body`.  I think that my headers from the SDK mixes with the ones from the DDK. How to fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DDK should only ever be used to develop a driver.  It is water and fire in user mode, lots of declarations overlap with the SDK headers.

Using NtLoadDriver() from user mode is undocumented, no header is available to get a declaration and there is no import library available for ntdll.dll.  It is a native operating system api function, even its argument uses a non-standard format for the registry key.  The native OS is very different from the Win32 api.  If you really, really want to do this then you'll have to write your own declaration and use GetProcAddress() to get the entrypoint in ntdll.dll

But loading drivers from user mode code is already well supported in Windows.  Best to use the documented and supported way, OpenSCManager + CreateService.  A sample project is [available here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31905/A-C-class-wrapper-to-load-unload-device-drivers).

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't do this. `DDK` headers are exclusively for driver development and shouldn't be included in applications source code. If you need to load driver, you should use the `NtLoadDriver` function which is a user mode version of `ZwLoadDriver`. Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566470%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Also from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554288%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

"*User-mode applications use the native system services routines by calling the entry points in the Ntdll.dll dynamic link library. These entry points convert calls to Nt and Zw routines into system calls that are trapped to kernel mode. To access these entry points, a user-mode application statically links to the Ntdll.lib library, which is available in the WDK. The routines that are implemented in Ntdll.lib are stubs that dynamically link to the entry points in Ntdll.dll at run time*".

Comment: What header contains `NtLoadDriver`, what should I include ?

Comment: Read the quoted paragraph: you should statically link to `Ntdll.lib`